# How to enumerate equations?

Tags: equations, numbering, lists

I want to enumerate equations in the following way:

- An equation is in the same line as the bullet sign.
- All equations are align to the left.
- The number of an equation is align to the right.

Any suggestions how to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newdimen\mymathindent
\newenvironment{bulletequation}%
    {\@beginparpenalty\predisplaypenalty
     \@endparpenalty\postdisplaypenalty
     \refstepcounter{equation}%
     \trivlist \item[]\leavevmode
       \hb@xt@\linewidth\bgroup $\m@th% $
         \displaystyle
         \hskip\mymathindent}%
        {$\hfil % $
         \displaywidth\linewidth\hbox{\@eqnnum}%
       \egroup
     \endtrivlist}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \begin{bulletequation} 1+2=3\end{bulletequation}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Khalinghi: This is exactly what I was looking for, I will have to get more deep into TeX to understand how this works, but it works!

Answer (score 12):

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\Item$#1${\item $\displaystyle#1$
   \hfill\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item foo
\Item $ 1+2=3 $
\item bar
\Item $f(x)=\int\limits_a^bx^2\mathrm{d}x$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is even simpler solution, but as far as I see all equations will be numbered, what if I want to number only some equations in the list?

Comment: @Tomek: a very simple solution is to define `\def\ItemNN$#1${\item $\displaystyle#1$}` which is a math item with NoNumber `\ItemNN`. However, in this case you can simply type your equation like `\item $\displaystyle y=f(x)$` that's all.