# amsart and enumerate environment

Tags: equations, lists, horizontal-alignment, enumerate, amsart

I'm using the `amsart` documentclass. Now the equation numbers are aligned to the left, I'm okay with that but what bothers me is the following: If I have equations in an `enumerate` environment it centers the equations with respect to the whole page. To me that doesn't look very good. How do I center the equation with respect to the body of the `enumerate` environment?

Comment: @Jonas: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have a look at [How to enumerate equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10669/how-to-enumerate-equations). There are solutions for itemize environments which may be used for enumerate environments as well.

Comment: @Jonas: Or do you still want the equations centered, but centered in the part of the text _without the additional left margin?_

Comment: @Hendrik: Exactly, that is what I want!

Comment: @Jonas: OK, that's what I thought. I've taken the liberty to try and clarify your question a bit.

Comment: Does one of the solutions in [“How can I center text/math inside a list environment?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11606/how-can-i-center-text-math-inside-a-list-environment) work with `amsart`?

Comment: @Jonas: Just to point that out: The page Caramdir linked to solves the _opposite_ problem, but the methods could well work for your problem, too.

Comment: @Hendrik: I will try them and see if it works, thanks!

Comment: @Hendrik: You are right, I misread that.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93952/left-numbered-equation-inside-list-environment/93978#93978

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't want the equations to be numbered, you can use the following:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\newenvironment{shiftequation}
{%
  \par\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \begin{equation*}
}
{%
  \end{equation*}
  \end{minipage}
}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's some
text. Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's
some text. Here's some text.
\begin{equation*}
  \sin^{2} x + \cos^{2} x =
  \int_{0}^{1} \bigl(\sin x + \cos x\bigr)^{4}\, dx +
  \int_{-1}^{1} \bigl(\log(x^{3}) + \sin^{5} (x^{5})\bigr)^{4}\,dx
\end{equation*}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's
  some text. Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's some
  text. Here's some text. Here's some text.
  \begin{shiftequation}
  \sin^{2} x + \cos^{2} x =
  \int_{0}^{1} \bigl(\sin x + \cos x\bigr)^{4}\, dx +
  \int_{-1}^{1} \bigl(\log(x^{3}) + \sin^{5} (x^{5})\bigr)^{4}\,dx
  \end{shiftequation}
\item Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's
  some text. Here's some text. Here's some text. Here's some
  text. Here's some text. Here's some text.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Alas, if you try the same thing with a numbered display (i.e., changing `equation*` to `equation`), then the equation numbers line up with the left margin of the text inside the `enumerate` environment, rather than with the left edge of the overall text area.