# Left numbered equation inside list environment

Tags: math-mode, lists, amsmath, enumerate, mathtools

I use the `mathtools` package with the `leqno` option in the `memoir` class. When inside a `list` environment, the equation label is misaligned.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[leqno]{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Inside list:
  \begin{equation}
    x=y.
  \end{equation}
\end{enumerate}

Outside list.
\begin{equation}
  x\neq y.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Does anyone know a workaround to this? I've tried changing some list spacing lengths before the display environment but that did not work.

Comment: I'm afraid it is a "feature"

Comment: interesting question.  `amsmath` ordinarily sets the equation number flush left, even within a list, and many people have requested that it be aligned with the left margin of the list item text.  this is the first time i've ever seen a request for the number to be moved to the "real" left margin.  (i don't know how `mathtools` or `memoir` has changed this.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a "feature" of the standard classes; however the AMS classes offer a way out:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[leqno]{mathtools}

%%% ADDED CODE FROM amsbook.sty
\newcommand\fullwidthdisplay{\displayindent0pt \displaywidth\columnwidth}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \everydisplay\expandafter{\expandafter\fullwidthdisplay\the\everydisplay}
}
%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Inside list:
  \begin{equation}
    x=y.
  \end{equation}
\end{enumerate}

Outside list.
\begin{equation}
  x\neq y.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The equations will be centered to the line width, which is probably what you want.

However, the equation number will conflict with the item numbers; I prefer right equation numbers, in general, and particularly for these situations.

[image]

Comment: Nice, it works well. I think now that the numbers on the right are indeed more aesthetically pleasing in this situation. However, I think that removing the display indent in the list environments gives a better look, even with numbers on the right, because of the equation alignment.

Comment: @Dimas That's what the AMS classes do. Not everybody agrees. I simply try avoiding displayed equations in lists. :) Welcome to TeX.SX! (I forgot to say it in my first comment, sorry.)