# enumerating an equation which is tagged

Tags: enumerate

Hi I need to enumerate (on the left) using roman numerals an equation which is centered and has a tag on the right.

Example:

> (i)        x-2=3          (E1)

Is there a way to insert roman numeral to itemize before `\begin{equation}`?

Comment: have you seen [How to number equations with a list environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88742) ? It looks similar, or at the very least, relevant

Comment: If the answer below solved your problem, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

There are some possibilities and solutions for similar things here like [How to enumerate equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10669/how-to-enumerate-equations)

If you need only single line equations the solution below should work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\myItem}[2]{\item[(#1)] \hfill #2   \hfill
   \refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\myItem{iv}{$1 = 2 -1$}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```